# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist for extension

Tags: magento-1.9

My magento database is created using table prefix.
After installing extension the **table is created with prefix**.
But while using the extension to save the data it throws exception as
 "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  **(databasename.without prefix table name)** doesn't exist" 
for extension but the **table name is present with prefix**.
How to resolve it.
Where to make changes since in many of the extension it throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the installation script that installed this table hardcoded the script. Something like `install-x.x.x.php` instead of `$this->getTable('.../...')`.

So, check all of your extensions' `sql` directory scripts and confirm that the table names are hardcoded. If that's the case, you'll have to just update your table names with your prefix included.

Comment: I am the newbie, could you pls explain briefly?

Comment: I am trying to install this module, http://www.lanot.biz/lanot-easy-sticker.html. Afer moved to root folder, website not working, it's getting the blank page. and if i click product edit page screenshot like https://snag.gy/1GlTse.jpg

Comment: how to create the table without hard coded values, can you pls update it